# How to create a Powershell Alias for Set-Executionpolicy

Tags: powershell

Following guides to create an alias in powershell, I have run the following command:

```
Set-Alias rush-enable "Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope Process -ExecutionPolicy Bypass"
```

This sets the alias. However when I run the alias I hit an error.

```
PS C:\example> rush-enable                
rush-enable : The term 'Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope Process       
-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted' is not recognized as the name of  
a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the  
spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that     
the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ rush-enable
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Set-ExecutionPo.  
   ..cy Unrestricted:String) [], CommandNotFoundException        
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

However running the command on it's own works fine:

```
PS C:\example> Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope Process -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
PS C:\example>
```

Am I missing something? How should I format the command to work as an alias?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_aliases?view=powershell-7.2#alternate-names-for-commands-with-parameters):

> You can assign an alias to a cmdlet, script, function, or executable
> file.
>
> You **cannot assign an alias to a command and its parameters**. For
> example, you can assign an alias to the `Get-Eventlog` cmdlet, but you
> cannot assign an alias to the `Get-Eventlog -LogName System` command.

This is presumably a way to avoid having to disambiguate a parameter that exists on an alias and which is passed when invoking the alias.

You therefore have two options:

1. Encapsulate your command in a function called `Enable-Rush` (note the [PowerShell acceptable naming scheme](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/cmdlet/approved-verbs-for-windows-powershell-commands?view=powershell-7.2), if you care). In your case this would look something like:

```
function Enable-Rush {
    Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope Process -ExecutionPolicy Bypass
}
```

2. Save the command as a file and create a alias to the file.

And to persist it, put it in a [`$PROFILE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_profiles?view=powershell-7.2). Depending on your system, you might need to digitally sign the `$PROFILE` or [change the PowerShell system Execution Policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_signing?view=powershell-7.2) to allow PowerShell scripts generated by the system to execute when starting a PowerShell process.